# Do we need to catch the return value of AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-asynctask, downloading-website-files

I have written an Async task below

```
   public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String result = "";
            HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                int data = reader.read();
                while (data != -1){
                    char currentData = (char)data;
                    result+=currentData;
                    data = reader.read();
                }
                Log.i("Downloaded data",result);
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Here the AsyncTask returns a `string` value.
In the `onCreate` method I have called the object of this AsyncTask

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        titles = new ArrayList<String>();
        arrayAdapter =new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,titles);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        //To get json data
        DownloadTask task  = new DownloadTask();
        try {
            task.execute("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty");
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

This code works without an error. But my doubt is don't we need a variable of type string to catch the returned value of AsyncTask. Here no variable is used and it's simply written as `task.execute("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty");`. Why doesn't this raise an error. Can anybody please explain. I am new to Android.

Comment: @user:10819573 could you please look into it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of `AsyncTask.execute(Params... params)` is the task itself as stated in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask#execute(Params...)), so that you can keep a reference of it. If you just ignore the return value, this does not result in an error.

An `AsyncTask` works asynchronously. That's why you  retrieve the result later in the `onPostExecute(Result result)` method of the `AsyncTask`. This method is run on the UI thread, so you can update views, etc. there.